# How to write one whole expression to get the column's weighted sum?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum

The  data column contains four value:1,1,2,3 in a excel table,every data has its weight, weight for 1 is 0.9,weight for 2 is 0.8,weight for 3 is 0.7,i want the weighted sum.

[image]

1.Write the expression `=IF($A2=1,0.9,IF($A2=2,0.8,IF($A2=3,0.7)))` in `B2`.
2.Drag the fill handle from `B2` till `B5`.
3.Write the expression `=sum(B2:B5)` in `B6`.

I get the right sum in `b6`,can i delete `B` column and write a single expression in `B1` to get weighted sum?That is to say,merge step1,step2,step3 into a one single expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different `SUMPRODUCT` can be used for differing weights:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE(A2:A5,0.9,0.8,0.2))
```

Note that this is an array formula and will need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Nice. For the record, you won't need `SUMPRODUCT`, just `SUM` will do when you have to `CSE` a formula =)

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1-(A2:A5*0.1))
```

[image]

---

If you want to hard code the values then I suggest using INDEX/MATCH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX({0.9,0.8,0.2},MATCH(A2:A5,{1,2,3},0)))
```

Then you can change the arrays to anything you like.

[image]

Comment: No, what about the weight for 3 is 0.2?

Comment: If the weight for 3 is 0.2 ,the weighted sum is 2.8,not 3.3 then.

Comment: you question states that 3 is .7 not .2